# Как сделать кнопку с двумя надписями?

Tags: android, xml, вёрстка, button, customview

Здравствуйте.
Нужно создать кнопку, с собственной разметкой (2 строки текста). Образец:
[image: Образец]
На данном примере реализовано через:

```
<RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout>
  <TextView/>
  <TextView/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

В данном случае проблема в том, что нельзя анимировать нажание (смена цвета).

---

Как собрать свою кнопку? или в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень даже можно анимировать нажатие чего угодно.
Вешаете вот такого типа XML drawable на атрибут `android:background` и будет вам смена цвета или еще чего.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light"/>
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Это образец, цвета свои сами подставьте для каждого состояния.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №1. Задавать надпись на кнопке через `Spanned`:

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml("<big>Строка 1</big><br/><small>Строка 2</small>");
button.setText(spanned);
```

Вариант №2. Сделать свою кастомную кнопку
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615433/3356946